# Using webpack and publicPath for static resources

Tags: javascript, webpack

The following question was rewritten, because I have now a working solution, but no answer to the question above.

The repository that shows different scenarios how to use resources packed with `webpack` is named [example-webpack-dynamic-resources](https://github.com/mliebelt/example-webpack-dynamic-resources). It contains 3 modules:

- inline: a solution, but not useful in my context (many resource files)
- file: a solution by using the plugin [webpack-require-from](https://github.com/agoldis/webpack-require-from)
- public-path: no solution yet, shows how I would like to use `__webpack?public_path__`.

I think I have read any resource about webpack and `publicPath` and `__webpack_public_path__`, but I don't get it to work. I try to dynamically change the path to static resources, but it fails.

Here is my context:

- I build a Javascript library that will be used on web pages (HTML, CSS, Javascript).
- It provides a lot (>100) static resources to small image files, combined > 500 KB. Only a fraction of it will be used by the user looking at the web site.
- Therefore I would like to pack the CSS into the bundle, but keep the image resources in a directory located on the server somewhere. The default path to it will be `/img`.
- As long as I use the same structure (which means, images only under `ROOT/img/**`, everything is ok.
- But the users of the library should be able to configure the path to the image resources on their will.

You will find all relevant files in my example repository [example-webpack-dynamic-resources](https://github.com/mliebelt/example-webpack-dynamic-resources) in the module `public-path-resources`.

- `webpack.js`: Use file-loader for images, which are referenced in CSS files. CSS will be inlined by style-loader and css-loader.
- `src/public-path.js`: Define the global variable with a default (no environment variable).
- `src/index.js`: require first `public-path`, then the logic.
- `examples/exam1-root/index.html`: Tries to use the assets in the sub directory `lib`, sets the value therefore to `__webpack_public_path__ = '/lib/`. Not working.
- `examples/exam2-different-dirs/index.html`: Moves the library to a different dir (not relevant), but uses the originally defined directory `pgnv-assets` for the assets. Working.
- `examples/exam3-non-standard-dirs/index.html`: Try to use instead `my-assets` as directory for the assets. Not working.

How could the `__webpack_public_path__` defined at runtime in the index.html file?

Comment: are you trying to change __webpack_public_path__ dynamically?

Comment: Perhaps it would be best, if you create a little demo repo and a little readme with what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Legends By trying to create an example, I just accidentally had something working. The problems seems to be to have the assets served differently. By inlining them, the problem went away. I have to check if that is a valid solution to my problem. Perhaps I have to package those images differently ...

Comment: @mliebelt Yeah, that's why we always ask for a repo which reproduces the problem. Oftenly when people purify the code in order to make a reproducable example, they find the problem by themselves ;-) If not, just update the question with a repo link.